# Can I use skos:broader to relate two skos:ConceptScheme?

Tags: rdf, modeling, semantic-web, skos

Can I use skos:broader to relate two skos:ConceptScheme? if no, then how can we relate them if they have parent-child relation between them?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `skos:ConceptScheme`s having a parent-child relationship?

Comment: @BenCompanjen thanks for your reply. Suppose we have two conceptScheme "A" and "B".  "B" is narrower to "A".  So, in this case can we use skos:broader and skos:narrower between "A" and "B"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `skos:broader` and `skos:narrower` properties cannot be used with Concept Schemes. Any subject and object used with these properties are said to be Concepts and given that Concept and Concept Scheme are defined to be disjoint classes, you would get logical inconsistencies.

I am not sure what you want to express precisely if you say you have broader/narrower Concept Schemes.
To relate Concept Schemes, you could use any other property (or invent your own) that has the meaning you need.

You *can* say that a Concept from Scheme A is narrower than a Concept from Scheme B using `skos:narrower`, because Concepts with a semantic relation do not have to be in the same Scheme:

> (…) note that using the SKOS semantic relation properties (skos:broader, skos:narrower, skos:related) to link concepts in different concept schemes is also consistent with the SKOS data model (…).

[SKOS Reference, §10.6.1. Mapping Properties, Semantic Relation Properties and Concept Schemes](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#L4160)